# How to get URL of deployed App Engine Project

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I have deployed my app in App Engine using maven (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven)

How can I programmatically get the URL of the APP?
I know it follows this format *https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com*. However, I do not know the region Id. If there is no way to get the URL, is there a way to get the region ID?

*edit*

I found this to be useful for this purpose:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/get

Comment: You can get the region ID from the Google cloud console.  It is fixed so no need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know that it is fixed, but in my case I have no access to it. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I know that the command gcloud app describe can show this, but I was hoping there was a better way than retrieving the stdout from the command

Comment: looks like you are all set now.  It is good practice to answer your own question when you figure it out on your own.

Comment: @gaefan Not quite? She's asking for the regionID, and how to get it programatically, `gcloud app describe` and `apps.get` give you a locationID not a regionID. Still, you're not wrong in saying it's a good practice.

Comment: EDIT: Hang on, no, I'm an idiot, you're right. They're the same thing, I was thinking about Zones, not Regions (can't edit the original because I was too slow to notice, there's a 5 minute limit)

Answer (score 2):

This command will get the URL of the deployed App Engine:

```
gcloud app browse
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code on my production env to identify the URL. Getting of ***REGIONID*** dynamically using code is not possible for now. At least in my current SDK it is not available. Someday they will do that.

For now ***REGIONID.r*** is not mandatory in the URL as per the Google documentation. It might be required in future projects. This code will work for you.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#region-id

```
import com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;
import com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String projectId = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId().indexOf("~")>-1?
                ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId().split("~")[1]:ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId();
    ModulesService ssf = ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService();
    String url = null;
    if(SystemProperty.environment.value()!=SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
        url = "http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER";
    }
    if(ssf.getDefaultVersion(ssf.getCurrentModule()).equals(ssf.getCurrentVersion())) {
        //This is default version
        url = "https://" + projectId + ".appspot.com";
    }
    //The URL with the current version ID  
    url = "https://" + ssf.getCurrentVersion() + "-dot-" + projectId + ".appspot.com";
    //The URL with the module name, current version name
    url = "https://" + ssf.getCurrentVersion() + "-dot-" + ssf.getCurrentModule() + "-dot-" + projectId + ".appspot.com";

}
```